# udp for large data file

Tags: java, udp

I need to transfer a big data file (image file) using UDP protocol in Java. Any resources / links to do it will be helpful.

Comment: This sounds like homework! In the real world you'd use TCP...

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you will need is a layer to add reliability. http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+reliable+udp
UDP is not reliable and any or all of the image could be lost unless you have a protocol on top of UDP to make it reliable.

I suggest you impliment this using TCP first as this is much simpler, and change it to UDP if you feel you still need to later.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [trivial file transfer protocol (TFTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol) - it implements a file transfer over UDP.

In real life, when not limited to UDP, you would use something TCP-based, as you have to implement everything again what TCP gives you over UDP, and most probably you would do this less efficient than your TCP-stack could have done.